# Best way to user current user in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i get a user by json request in android i have a one class, example:

```
public class CurrentUser {
    public static String first_name = "";

    public static String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public static void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        CurrentUser.first_name = first_name;
    }
 }
```

and i class in mi activity class

```
my_text.settext(CurrentUser.getFirst_name());
```

But when app is in background i lose the data, existing any options without shared preferences?

Comment: you need to save the data persistently such as in a database.  Just use asynchronous request to send your data in your database, you will need to create apis(urls) that will be hit on request to send and obtain the data as needed, those urls will be hosted on your webservice.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one option but all leads to the same. You need to store this data manually. Using a `saveInstanceState` is an option, but it won't survice app closing. Other hand you can store it to the database using `sqlite`/`realm or` whatever you like.

Comment: my dude.. its correct use static variables in class for current user?

Comment: no just dont do it. You don't have control on static variable lifecycle.